# Gremlin: get a count of people by location where the name of the location starts with "US"

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

The below results in a group count of people by location name:
g.V()hasLabel('people').out('people_location').groupCount().by('name')

I tried this to filter the list of locations by only those that begin with US:
g.V()hasLabel('people').out('people_location').groupCount().by('name').matches("US*")

and
g.V()hasLabel('people').out('people_location').matches("US*").groupCount().by('name')

but neither work.

Answer (score 0):

What is `matches()`? Is that an OrientDB-specific step? For now, I'll just assume that this might be the main problem here, as I'm not aware of `matches` step. This is what I would do:

```
g.V().hasLabel('people').
  out('people_location').has('name', gte('US').and(lt('UT'))).
  groupCount().
    by('name')
```

or, even simpler:

```
g.V().has('location', 'name', gte('US')).
  group().
    by('name').
    by(inE('people_location').count())
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried this but gte('US') is returning all labels and not filtering by just the ones that begin with US. is there another option?

Comment: Sorry, should have been `gte('US').and(lt('UT'))`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel. This isn't working either :( 

I have added an updated version of this question since there are additional fields I want to try and get. Maybe you can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302510/gremlin-generate-a-list-by-location-of-counts-for-active-versus-inactive-users

Comment: what version of Gremlin are you using and what version of OrientDB?

Comment: Is this issue not a duplicate of your other issue Veronica?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302510/gremlin-generate-a-list-by-location-of-counts-for-active-versus-inactive-users